# How to prevent re-render ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, state

I have this data from selector.

```
const { notification } = useSelector(state => state.notification)
```

Then I check if the notification data is exist and valid with useEffect.

```
useEffect(() => {
if (notification && notification.length) {
  // I store the data using state
  setToastData(notification.find((item) => !item.is_read))
}}, [notification])
```

Then if the toastdata is exist, I show my component.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (toastData) {
      toastRef.current.show()
    }
  }, [toastData])
```

How to prevent toastRef.current.show() run, if notification and toastData is not change?

Comment: pass notification with toastData in effect dependency array

Comment: Do you mean to pass it in single useEffect?

Comment: could you please elaborate more on when you expect to show the toast? and when the notification data change ? if you can provide some simple codesandbox to show what you want exactly